# regex for comma-delimited list of two possible valid strings

Tags: regex

I'm looking to create a regex that would match either `xxx` or `yyy`, or any combination separated by commas.

So these would be valid:

```
xxx
yyy
xxx,xxx
yyy,xxx
xxx,yyy,yyy,yyy
```

But these would be invalid:

```
xx // must be exact xxx
yyyy // must be exact yyy
xxx, // trailing comma
xxxyyy // no delimiter
xxx,,yyy // should only have one comma between
,xxx,yyy // no prepending commas
```

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should suffice `^((?:xxx|yyy)(,(?:xxx|yyy))*)$`. https://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5/1327

Comment: Updated it, it matched the `xxxyyy` case before, sry.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *[negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)* like this:

```
^((xxx|yyy)(,(?!$)|$))+$
```

[See it on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hPERQK/2).

Compared to [Eraklon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60355482/6231376) this regex doesn't repeat `(xxx|yyy)` part twice, but it's a little less performant.